# Count How many times a value appeared in a column(excel)

Tags: excel, count, frequency, countif, vba

Ok, So I have an excel file that have a column that may contain duplicate value like this

**PO NUMBER          PO COUNT**
P100293490                      4
P100293490
P100293490
P100293490
P100293492                  2
P100293492
P100293494                  3
P100293494
P100293494
P100293497                  4
P100293497
P100293497
P100293497
P100293499                  1
P100293490                  2
P100293490
P100293492                  1

I need to count how many times it appeared on the column and place it beside the first occurrence of the word. The problem is that the **PO NUMBER** is not sorted so values may repeat on the lower rows of the excel.  i tried everything (Lookup, Match, Countif, IF)
and nothing  seems to work. Please Help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: `=COUNTIF()` seems to be the straightforward solution here.

Comment: @Unihedron tried it with no luck. it counts the occurrence in that whole column . :/

Comment: What exactly did you use (for `COUNTIF` arguments)? You should post it so troubleshooting is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data as you give it is in `A1:B18` (with headers in row 1), enter this in `B2`:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:A$1000<>A2,),)-1,"")
```

Copy down as required.

Amend the 1000 to a sufficiently higher row reference if necessary.

Comment: Wow. its you again :)
how are you so good at excel? thanks again :)

Comment: Haha! Too much misspent time, I guess! And you're welcome again!